# JAVA Generics - How to pass class itself as an argument

Tags: java, generics

This is in Java. Sorry I have been looking for this all morning but am still confused.

Say I got a method `getClassName`;

```java
public static String getClassName (Class<? extends A> myClass) {
   return myClass.getSimpleName;
}
```

I got classes `B`, `C` both extending `A`.

My questions are as follows:

1. The Parameter is a type parameter, so any class that conforms Class `A` (so classes `A`, `B`, `C`) can be pass ed in?
2. How do actually call `getClassName` in `main`?  Specifically how to pass in class itself as method argument?

Comment: 1. yes 2. how about B.class?

Answer (score 0):

If method is in same class as from you are calling then it may look like this:

```
getClassName(A.class);
getClassName(B.class);
```